# REGEXP with QSlQuery fails

Tags: regex, qt, qt5

Using Qt 4.8 and sql I tried to find a record (field = NomTri) in a sqlite3 database using the query command:

```
...
QSqlRecord rec = db.record (table);//table is the sqlite opened database
QSqlQuery q;
QString cmd = "SELECT * FROM Individus WHERE NomTri REGEXP 'LEF*.BURE'";
bool flag = q.exec(cmd);
...
```

but I got flag = false meaning the command isn't executed.

If I use the same command (SELECT * FROM Individus WHERE NomTri REGEXP 'LEF*.BURE') with DB Browser for SQLite its works perfectly. Why?

NB: I also tried to escape but without success:

```
QString cmd = "SELECT * FROM Individus WHERE NomTri REGEXP \'LEF*.BURE\'";
```

Any idea?

Comment: Replace `*.` with `.*\\.`, or maybe ``[^']*\\.`` will work better.

Comment: @Wiktor I tried your solution but without more success...
I wonder if REGEXP (the SQLite query parameter) is compatible with SQLITE driver?
I did'nt find any source example using it...

Comment: If you use a regex, and want to match a string like `LEFno-idea-what-may-be-here-but-no-single-quotes-BURE`, you may use `LEF[^']*BURE`. Do you mean you just need `QString cmd = "LEF[^']*BURE";`?

Comment: @Wiktor What I mean is when I use the string command in DB Browser for SqLite, it works, but when I try to insert this command in Qt code with bool flag = q.exec(cmd) where QSqlQuery q; the command is not executed (as flag is false).

Comment: I am not sure what is happening because 1) `LEF*.BURE` is not a good regex, and must contain a user error - namely, it matches `LEFFFFFFF$BURE`, while, I suspect it needs to match `LEF something here..!@@ BURE`. 2) I am not sure you are using a regex in a method that supports it. 3) The statements you query DB with should usually be "prepared". I am not sure thus, I can't help you. Just suggesting various things to have a look at.

Comment: @Wiktor What I do mean is when I use the string command in DB Browser for SqLite, it works, but when I try to insert this command in Qt code with bool flag = q.exec(cmd) where QSqlQuery q; the command is not executed (as flag is false).
so, I add QSqlError err = q.lastError(); to be able to see in the debugger what happens; I got this:
dataBaseError "no such function: REGEXP"
driverError "Unable to execute statement"
errorNumber 1
errorType QSqlError::StatementError(2)

Comment: Ok, that clears things out. SQLite does not have its own REGEXP operator implementation, you need to add your own.